# How to know which Graphics API is being used internally in C++?

Tags: c++, dll

I would like to know if there is any way to know which API is being used by the process in which my DLL was injected (such as D3D9, DXD11, DXD12, OpenGL, Vulkan, etc...), I searched a lot but didn't find anything specifically for dll's.

Answer (score 1):

found a method that works and it's pretty simple, just look for the specific API module, like:

```
if (GetModuleHandle("d3d12.dll") != NULL) {
        return "D3D12";
}
if (GetModuleHandle("d3d11.dll") != NULL) {
        return "D3D11";
}
```

And so it goes, with any other graphics API

Comment: This approach will only work when only a single graphics API dll is linked. In case the engine supports, for example, both DX11 and DX12, you can't find out which one is really used.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the actual differences between the implementations of D3D 10, 11, and 12 are essentially nonexistent as they all funnel down to the same DDI, thus differentiating the API calls at runtime may be borderline impossible given how much they wrap over each other.